# JSTL JSP Include Servlet Makes JSP Blank

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I'm writing a section of code to display a list of organizations that come from a MYSQL database. I'm using JDBC Realm form authentication so I know my database can be queried and runs properly. My JSP page displays everything like normal when I exclude the servlet, but when I include it, my page displays blank with just the background color of my css and nothing else. I greatly appreciate any help in figuring out why this is occurring and/or a workaround so that I may display this list from the database. All relevant code included below:

JSP Page in Question:

```
<%@page import="SW.models.StudentOrg"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:include page="GetOrgServlet" flush="true" />
<c:import url="/includes/header.html" />
<body>
    <div id='container'>

        <c:import url="/includes/navigation.html" />

        <aside>
            <img src='https://projecthelping.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Your-Logo-here.png' width="200" height="200"   alt='Organization Logo'>
            <h3>[List of Upcoming Events Here]</h3>
            <p>[Contact Information Here]</p>
        </aside>

        <section id='main'>

            <h2>[Student Organization Name Here]</h2>   
            <p>
                [Student Organization Description Here] 
            </p>

            <p>
                [Student Organizations Q&A Section Here]
            </p>

            <table>
                <th>Org ID</th>
                <th>Org Name</th>
                <th>Org Description</th>
                    <c:forEach var="studentOrg" items="${studentOrgList.studentOrg}"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>${studentOrg.OrgID}</td>
                        <td>${studentOrg.OrgName}</td>
                        <td>${studentOrg.OrgDescription}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>

        </section>

        <c:import url="/includes/footer.jsp" />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet in Question:

```
package SW.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import SW.data.DB;
import SW.models.StudentOrg;
import SW.models.StudentOrgList;

public class GetOrgServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        StudentOrgList studentOrgList = DB.getStudentOrgs();
        session.setAttribute("studentOrgList", studentOrgList);

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

DB.java (where queries are stored, I'm using getStudentOrgs in the servlet)

```
package SW.data;

import java.sql.*;
import SW.models.*;

public class DB {

    public static StudentOrg selectStudentOrg(Integer OrgID) {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM org "
                + "WHERE OrgID = ?";
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, OrgID);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            StudentOrg studentOrg = null;
            if (rs.next()) {
                studentOrg = new StudentOrg();
                studentOrg.setOrgID(rs.getInt("orgID"));
                studentOrg.setOrgName(rs.getString("orgName"));
                studentOrg.setOrgDescription(rs.getString("orgDescription"));
            }
            return studentOrg;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
            DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
            pool.freeConnection(connection);
        }
    }

    public static StudentOrgList getStudentOrgs() {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM org";
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            StudentOrgList studentOrgList = new StudentOrgList();
            while (rs.next()) {
                StudentOrg studentOrg = new StudentOrg();
                studentOrg.setOrgID(rs.getInt("OrgID"));
                studentOrg.setOrgName(rs.getString("OrgName"));
                studentOrg.setOrgDescription(rs.getString("OrgDescription"));
                studentOrgList.addStudentOrg(studentOrg);
            }
            return studentOrgList;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
            DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
            pool.freeConnection(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture of Table being Queried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0bt0.png)

Connection Pool

```
package SW.data;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ConnectionPool {

    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    private ConnectionPool() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/milestone3");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ConnectionPool getInstance() {
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new ConnectionPool();
        }
        return pool;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void freeConnection(Connection c) {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseUtil

```
package SW.data;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBUtil {

    public static void closeStatement(Statement s) {
        try {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void closePreparedStatement(Statement ps) {
        try {
            if (ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void closeResultSet(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I don't necessarily need to display the list this way, it's just one way of doing it that I thought I knew how to do as I'd done so previously, but something seems to be amiss and I can't find it anywhere. So I appreciate any suggestions about this solution or a different one!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe try putting studentOrgList on request `request.setAttribute("studentOrgList", studentOrgList);`

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. It's a very odd issue that no one seems to have gotten exactly based on what I'm finding online.

Comment: try this if it's on the session `${sessionScope.studentOrgList}`

Comment: also `${studentOrgList.studentOrg}` should be `${studentOrgList}`

Comment: What do you mean by domain class?